# Loading Date-Object from JSON would not work

Tags: swift

I read a JSON-String from my api with a Date-Array.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "headline": "How to messure the T8",
    "descriptiontext": "Learn how to messure the T8",
    "adddate": {
        "date": "2022-03-02 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "changedate": {
        "date": "2022-03-02 00:00:00.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    }
}
]
```

I had add a datemodel to the the class. without the date my decoding works and the objects would be viewed. But it seems that i have a fail in my decoding of the date.

Here is my struct

```
// MARK: - TutorialModel
struct TutorialModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let adddate, changedate: CustomDateModel
    let headline, descriptiontext: String
}

// MARK: - CustomDateModel
struct CustomDateModel: Codable {
    let date: String
    let timezoneType: Int
    let timezone: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date
        case timezoneType
        case timezone
    }
}
```

And here is the part, were i try to Decode the JSON

```
guard let newTutorials = try? JSONDecoder().decode([TutorialModel].self, from: data) else { return }
         DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
             self?.tutorials = newTutorials
         }
```

Could it be, that I have to read the data in a other way?

Comment: Don't `try?`, never do that in a `Decodable` context. Catch and print the error with  `do { try JSONDecoder()... } catch { print(error) }`. **HInt: Check the `CodingKeys`**.  And – unrelated to the issue – `[weak self]` is pointless. `DispatchQueue` closures don't cause retain cycles.

Comment: At least one coding key is wrong. case timezoneType = "timezone_type"

Comment: @vadian `DispatchQueue` closures do cause retain. The difference is that they don't usually form a cycle because the closure gets removed after execution. In most cases `weak self` is not necessary but there are cases when it is, especially if the closure is not executed immediately.

Comment: @Sulthan OK, I specify. ***This kind** of `DispatchQueue` closure doesn't cause a retain cycle*